# "Open in Terminal" from Nautilus not working

Tags: scripts, nautilus, 19.10, bashrc

OS: Ubuntu 19.10.

I use Nautilus as file manager, and I modified `~/.bashrc` file to open the terminal in another directory rather than `Home`. Let's call the target directory `$(MYDIR)`. Now, the problem is that if I press `Right Click -> Open in Terminal`  in Nautilus, it opens the terminal in `$(MYDIR)`, and that's because I think it executes the line of code I wrote in `~/.bashrc`.

Is there a way to fix this? I would like to open `$(MYDIR)` with `ctrl-alt-t` , but I would also like to open any directory from Nautilus when I do `Open in Terminal`.
Can I have both?

I think I could do it by adding some code in `~/.bashrc` wrapping the line `cd $(MYDIR)` but I don't know how to do it.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: what is the 0S??

Comment: @PRATAP sorry I forgot. edited

Comment: i think you can create another terminal app in your local directory and bind ctrl alt T to open that..so your right click menu will not interfer that..

Comment: @PRATAP can you explain? i don't know how to do it, i'm pretty new in Ubuntu

Comment: Hi I just did this way.. `bash -c 'gnome-terminal --working-directory=$HOME/Music'` and binded it to keyboard shortcut.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gajGu.jpg

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkDjp.png local app in `$HOME/.local/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop` and its contents.. See the Exec line which is twice. This way when you click the Terminal Icon in dash or in all apps.. It opens the direcotry of your choice.. disable the CTRL ALT T Original shortcut and create the shortcut with above bash -c command. I dont see `.bashrc` need in this case. If you want to stick to `.bashrc` Then workaround needs to come from Experts. !!!!

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of changing the line `cd $mydir` in `~/.bashrc` file with something like `if [terminal opened with application or ctrl-alt-t]; then cd $mydir elif [opened from "open in terminal"]; then cd $"current dir selected in Nautilus" fi` but I don't know what to do the `if-else` things. I hope someone can help me with this, if not, I will use your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to edit *bashrc*, or other system settings, you can just create a shortcut for whatever you need and assign a key combination for it.

Go to Desktop Settings (depends what desktop environment you use) find *keyboard shortcuts* there you should see a list of already assigned commands in your system and you should see an option to add the *custom shortcut*.

For example I want my terminal to open with a specific directory, then add this command as a shortcut:

```
gnome-terminal -w /path/to/folder
```

And assign the key combination let's say <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and save it, now when you press it, it'll launch terminal with that directory.

Or you can use `-e` option to launch File Manager GUI

```
gnome-terminal -e  NameOfFileManager
```